# How to solve name expected error in intent on kotlin?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have "Name expected" error in my Intent() second argument.
Are there any missing arguments?

```
fun setListeners() {
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SignUpActivity.class)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write instead :

```
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SignUpActivity::class.java)
```